# Can we change the column header of Devexpress spreadSheet in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am using Devexpress SpreadSheet in MVC web application in ASP.net.

I want to change column header(A,B,C...).

If it is possible? Can someone give solution for that?